# Example environment with numbering, caption, "verbatim" content

Tags: numbering, environments, verbatim, examples

I need to use an example environment like the following.

```
\begin{example}[My Caption, mylabel]
My example text
\end{example}
```

It should show the text inside a verbatim environment, the caption (like a figure) `Example 1: My Caption` and the label `mylabel` to refer to the example.

Can anyone help me, please?

I tried with this, but it doesn't work with the verbatim environment.

```
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{example}
  \vspace{0.3cm} {\bf{Example \thechapter.\arabic{example}} - #1} \\ \sf
}{\vspace{0.3cm}}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter.\arabic{example}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've solved in this way.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{example}[1][]{
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code}
    \lstset{fancyvrb=true,basicstyle=\footnotesize,captionpos=b,xleftmargin=2em,#1}
}{}
```

And then using this sample:

```
\begin{example}[caption=My Caption,label=mylabel]
My example text
\end{example}
```